# how to hide native Tabbar when a new page gets pushed in flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, uitabbarcontroller

I have a FlutterViewController embedded in a `UITabbarController`, when a new page gets pushed in FlutterViewController, the `UITabbar` in native `UITabbarController` is still showing, is it able to hide the Tabbar when the new flutter page gets pushed, just like the property `hideBottomBarWhenPushed` in native iOS development works?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to push flutter page before I send a note to native,

```
native invoke self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

Then go back,

```
native invoke self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
```